# Мне нужно найти количество последовательностей не одинаковых чисел

Tags: java, алгоритм

Мне нужно найти количество последовательностей чисел, например, если входные данные: 1 1 1 2 8 8 3 3 3 0, тогда на выходе должно быть: 3.

Это количество последовательностей, мне также нужно найти последовательности неидентичных цифр.
 В приведенном выше примере для последовательности неидентичных чисел результат должен быть 2. 
Я написал алгоритм, который подсчитывает количество последовательностей и количество последовательностей неидентичных чисел, но алгоритм неправильно подсчитывает количество последовательностей. неидентичных номеров в некоторых случаях для ввода: 1 1 1 2 8 8 3 3 3 0 количество неидентичных чисел учитывается, даже если есть только одна цифра. 
Следовательно, мы рассматриваем 2 и 0 как последовательность не одинаковых чисел, 
если есть входные данные: 1 2 3 0 0 0 4 5 5 9 8, тогда последовательность неидентичных чисел будет 123, 4, 98 
Как это сделать?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] str_arr = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
        int arr[] = new int[str_arr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < str_arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(str_arr[i].trim());
        }
        int n = arr.length;
        int n_s = 0, n_s2 = 0;
        int res = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ) {
            int counter = 0;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ) {
                if (arr[i] != arr[j]) {
                    i = j;
                    break;
                }
                j++;
                if (j >= n - 1) i = j;
                counter++;
            }
            int counter2 = 0;
            for (int j = i; j < n-1; ) {
                if (arr[j] != arr[j + 1]) {
                    counter2++;
                } else {
                    i = j;
                    break;
                }
                if (j >= n - 1) i = j - 1;
                j++;
            }

            n_s2 += (counter2 >= 1) ? 1 : 0;
            n_s += (counter >= 1) ? 1 : 0;
        }
        System.out.println(n_s);
        System.out.println(n_s2);
    }
}
```

Comment: очень интересно, но ни...чего не понятно. переформулируйте вопрос пожалуйста.

Comment: @Nordfox Главная проблема написать алгоритм который будет считать в последовательности не одинаковые числа даже если это будет всего одна цифра. Например входные данные: 1 2 3 0 0 0 4 3 3 3 2 0 0. и на выходе мы должны посчитать сколько раз встречается не последовательность т.е мы должны вытащить 123, 4, 2

Comment: найти кол-во непоследовательностей среди последовательностей??)

Comment: Объясните, как вы бы вручную считали то, что вам нужно на каком-нибудь примере. Сейчас совсем не понятно, что вы имеете в виду.

Comment: нужно найти количество или вывести сами последовательности?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помучайте такой код

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] str_arr = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
    int arr[] = new int[str_arr.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < str_arr.length; i++) {
      arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(str_arr[i].trim());
    }

    int sequencesNumber = 0;
    int nonSequencesNumber = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
      if (arr[i - 1] == arr[i]) {
        if (arr[i] != arr[i + 1]) {
          sequencesNumber++;
        }
      } else {
        if (arr[i] != arr[i + 1]) {
          nonSequencesNumber++;
        }
      }
    }

    // проверяем границы
    if (arr.length > 2) {
      nonSequencesNumber +=
          ((arr[arr.length - 2] != arr[arr.length - 1] ? 1 : 0) + (arr[0] != arr[1] ? 1 : 0));
    } else if (arr.length == 2) {
      nonSequencesNumber += arr[0] != arr[1] ? 2 : 0;
      sequencesNumber = arr[0] == arr[1] ? 1 : 0;
    }

    System.out.println(sequencesNumber);
    System.out.println(nonSequencesNumber);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для `количество последовательностей. неидентичных номеров`, результат в `series`:

```
int state = 1;
int series = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i == n - 1 || arr[i] == arr[i+1]) {
        if (state == 0) {
            state = 1;
            series++;
        }
    else
        state = 0;
}
```